# Nether Spawns: Y Axis Relevant?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Alright, I have two spawns in the Normal World:

one at: (which I will call `Main`)

```
x: -22
y: 65
z: 261
```

and another at: (which I will call `Tower`)

```
x: 17
y: 244
z: 296
```

Yes, I know that I should have a distance between the two portals of 1024 on either the `x` or `y` axis, but shouldn't the scan in the Nether pick up the **closest** portal within a 128 block range?

Get this...

`Main` translates to:

```
x: -2.75
y: 8.125
z: 32.625
```

and `Tower` translates to:

```
x: 2.125
y: 30.5
z: 37
```

... in the Nether. Now, in the Nether, I have constructed two portals:

One at: (which I will call `nMain`)

```
x: -2
y: 60
z: 31
```

and the second at: (which I will call `nTower`)

```
x: 2
y: 67
z: 36
```

Now, `Main` links to `nMain` and `Tower` links to `nTower`, yet both `nMain` and `nTower` link to `Main`. I can't get `nTower` to link back to `Tower`, which is what I want.

I have:

```
Tower -> nTower
Main  -> nMain

nMain
      } Main
nTower
```

..but I want:

```
Tower <-> nTower
Main  <-> nMain
```

So, here is my question. Have I configured my Nether portals incorrectly in some way (as in, is Y-Axis now relevant?), or have I simply placed my Normal World portals **far** too close together (which would suck)?

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While converting between Overworld and Nether coordinates, only X and Z are scaled by 8, y remains the same (in your calculation y is also divided by 8). This is not the problem, actually.

Here is how it works: When you enter a portal, the game calculates the ideal point where you should appear on the other side (by scaling X and Z with 8). Then it searches the closest portal to *that ideal point*.

If you do the calculations backwards (Nether -> Overworld coordinates), you get that entering `nMain` will try to go to here in the Overworld (let's call it `nMainOut`):

```
x: -16
y: 60
z: 248
```

...and 'nTower' will go to here (let's call it `nTowerOut`):

```
x: 16
y: 67
z: 288
```

The game searches the closest portal to those 'out' points. For both of these 'out' points the closest portal happens to be the `Main` portal at:

```
x: -22
y: 65
z: 261
```

The distance between points is euclidean distance, that is

```
distance = sqrt( (x1-x0)^2 + (y1-y0)^2 + (z1-z0)^2 )
```

If we calculate the distance between `nTowerOut` and `Main` we get 55.1

If we calculate the distance between `nTowerOut` and `Tower` we get 177.2

That is why `nTower` goes to `Main`.

With your current setup, I'm afraid it is not possible to build a Nether portal that goes to your `Tower` portal, unless you move the `Main` portal down near bedrock and *also* move `nTower` near the top of the Nether.

Comment: Thank you so much! So the **Y axis is relevant** when dealing with portals! I am glad to know that there is something that I can do to link `Main` and `Tower`. Thank you so much for your very descriptive and thoughtful response.